# Reading from a text file with a static constant declared

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that will read the contents of a file and I'm able to read it successfully. What I'm also trying to do is maybe declare a static constant like max_number_of_players so that the data read does not exceed this. Is there a way that I can do this? My code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        String fileName = "Data/players.txt";

        File file = new File(fileName);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String line = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition to the while-loop:

```
int playerCount = 0;

while(in.hasNextLine() && playerCount++ < max_number_of_players){
    ...
```